# Get status updates from long runing post using angular $http

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm using angular to post to a mvc controller. This controller then sends a bunch of emails and it takes quite a while. Is it possible to get some sort of status updates from the server (say every 50 sent emails)?

The angular code:

```
$http.post('/users/send', { searchParams: $scope.search }).then(
            function (data) {
                $scope.status = data.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                $scope.status = error;
            }
        );
```

Mvc:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(SendEmailCriteria searchParams)
{
      /*process and send emails*/
     return Content(this.GetMessage(log.GetJson()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `POST` request will be received, response will be returned immediately with `Guid`, email's sending will be performed asynchronous via `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You will send your emails and update `Progress`(or you can save it at `Session`) after each iteration. Then, to know current progress, you should make `GET` request to new `Status` action to check it. `Guid` is needed to connect particular email's sending task with corresponding client, on which side, after `POST` request, you will periodically(each 5 seconds (not each 50 iterations as you desired) via `$interval`) call `Status` endpoint with recivied `guid` as query parameter, to update progress:

**ASP.NET MVC:**

```
static Dictionary<Guid, int> Progress = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendEmail(SendEmailCriteria searchParams)
{
     var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
         foreach(var email in emails)
         {                 
             Send(email);         
             Progress[guid] = (emails.IndexOf(email) + 1) * 100 / emails.Count;
         }
     });
     return Json(new {guid});
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Status(Guid guid)
{
     var progress = Progress[guid];
     if(progress == 100)
         Progress.Remove(guid);
     return Json(new {progress});
}
```

**AngularJS:**

```
$http.post('/users/SendEmail', { searchParams: $scope.search }).then(
    function (data) {
         var interval = $interval(function(){
             $http.get('/users/Status?guid=' + data.guid).then(
                 function(resp) {
                     $scope.progress = resp.progress;
                     if(resp.progress == 100)
                         $interval.cancel(interval);
                 },
                 function (error) {
                     $scope.status = error;
                     $interval.cancel(interval);
                 });
             }, 5000);
    },
    function (error) {
         $scope.status = error;
    }
);
```

Also you can use `SignalR`, to notify client about completed work without periodical server pulling.